# ipSecurityRestrictions.ipAddress required Error for azure cmd deployment

Tags: java, linux, azure, deployment

I use Azure to host my App Service (which is basically a Java Spring Boot project that allow to call an endpoint), and since I added a firewall (there is sensible data) and added the VNet to the App Service - Access Restrictions I cannot anymore deploy using the cmd.exe command lines.

The error is this:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:1.7.0:deploy (default-cli) on project myProject: ipSecurityRestrictions.ipAddress is required and cannot be null. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`

Of course, the link they provide if not helpful at all... I tried updating the version of dependencies I use in my pom.xml but no success. I tried adding different restrictions in the scm (deployment) access restrictions but no changes too.

As I saw in the Resource Explorer, the only ipAdress that could be missing is the one of the VNet but damn it do not require one, plus, if I try to manually add it it says that it is not allowed for VNet access restriction.

I read this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-java-stable) to setup the deployment and it worked perfectly before I need to add the VNet to the Access Restrictions.

If any of you just have a little idea on something I didn't already tried I'll be happy to hear it!

Thank you

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue. You may create a new web app and have another try.

Comment: I don't see how it could resolve this... If you need it, you can find more details in the question I asked on the Azure forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c5bdf71-8562-4b3a-8f18-64be669a68c3/cannot-deploy-to-app-service-since-waf-added?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a lot of discussions with Microsoft engineers and then the new plugin version of azure-webapp-maven-plugin 1.8 released in end October 2019 solved the issue...